# What is a good flight simulator for a beginner?

Tags: flight-training, flight-simulator, uk

I'm in the UK and I wish to learn to fly starting with a home computer simulator.
I have never flown and I am only interested in light aircraft. I need instruction from scratch: what the instruments are for, starting the aircraft, everything from the very start.

I need someone to recommend to me a good home computer simulator which comes with basic flight instruction.

Comment: If you seriously want to learn to fly and get a license you need to go to a CFI and take lessons from him or her. A flight sim will not help you at all in this situation.

Comment: MS Flight Simulator has a built-in training program that walks you through it. For X-Plane, there are [tutorials available.](http://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/forum/90-x-ppl-learn-to-fly/)

Comment: Hi Howard. Welcome to Aviation.SE. Have a quick read of the [help centre](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help), especially about what is on and off topic and what kind of questions are expected.Any question containing "can you recommend" is likely to be off topic. In addition, your question is very broad and cannot be answered with concise, factual answers. Do please ask specific questions (remember, search first, many will already have been asked) and have a look through the existing question list for a feel of how things are done around here.  Good luck. We look forward to more from you.

Comment: You might also find [this Q&A](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/738/can-microsoft-flight-simulator-help-me-learn-to-fly-or-make-me-a-better-pilot) interesting.

Comment: [Closely related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/738/62)

Answer (score 7):

Most commercially available flight simulators (MS FSX, X-Plane, Prepar3d) can make excellent training tools for a budding pilot.  But do take this caution to heart.

The cup has to be empty before it can be filled.

Applied to flight training, do not attempt to instruct yourself how to fly.  At best, you will develop a lot of bad habits which a CFI will have to root out and correct prior to being able to teach you correct airmanship techniques.

On the other hand these kinds of games, when set to use realistic flight models, can be excellent tools for practicing skills you learned when you flew with a CFI in the real thing.  Using a realistic simulator game in parallel with real world flight training can save you a lot of time and money in your training.  These sim games are also excellent for instrument training as much of the required instrument skillset is easily modeled by the computer.  While not approved as an official Flight Training Device for logging official flight time, these sims are extremely realistic - so much so that the same mistakes I make in FSX I will make in the real thing!

One cautionary note:  sims like FSX do model a number of details correctly whereas other ones like dangerous weather, flying at the extreme edges of the envelope, etc are not.  There are a number of scenarios (eg flying into thunderstorms) you can do in FSX which will get you killed in the real world.  Approach learning to fly in a game with caution and any instruction you receive from a CFI should supplant game derived knowledge.